# rails, pass parameters from controller to service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Rails.
In the view, I have a submit button. In the controller I want to use the input (an array) and pass it to a service.

In the controller I have tried:

```
class TestDemandController < ApplicationController
  
  def index
  end

  def create
    test_demand = TestDemandService.new(@params)
    test_demand.build(@params)
  end
```

In the service:

```
class TestDemandService

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input
  end

  def build(input)
     ..loop over an array..
  end
```

I have this error at the line "loop over an array":
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Thank you

Comment: use ```debugger``` or ```pry``` to find out what input has passed in.From what you have posted, i guess input is nil, ```@params``` should be ```params```?

Comment: https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: What is @params? Is this coming directly from the submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller you can access the params(what's being posted to the server with the form). You can check the params also in the terminal, they look like:
`Started POST ...... Parameters: {"key" => "value", "another_key" => "Another value"}`

To send the complete parameters to the service you can pass params to it:

```rb
  def create
    test_demand = TestDemandService.new(params)
    ...
  end
```

If you only want to send a specific value from the params you can do it like:

```rb
  def create
    test_demand = TestDemandService.new(params[:another_key])
    ...
  end
```

This will give you the value `another_value` in the service.

Comment: thank you! I have used binding.pry as suggested by Spike as used params[:another_key].